# form.cleaned_data not working in django

Tags: python, html, django

```
def kw(request):
    global form
    ans="this is the default value"        
    form = NameForm(initial={'C': ans})
    if form.is_valid():
        print("helooo")
        d = (form.cleaned_data['C'])

    print("the value of d =",d)
    return render(request, 'keyword.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my code but dont know why the form is not taken as valid .. 
neither the print("helooo') cmd is working nor the next one . 
if condition is not satisfied..

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    C = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

this is my form.py file

Answer (score 1):

`is_valid` will never return `True` if [the form is not bound](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/), and yours is not, because you didn't pass any data. You would need to instantiate the form like this:

```
form = NameForm(request.POST)
```

There are many other problems with your code. You can take a look at [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view) to see how you might structure a view that processes a form.

---

```
def kw(request):
    ans = "this is the default value"        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("helooo")
            d = (form.cleaned_data['C'])
            print("the value of d =",d)
    else:
        form = NameForm(initial={'C': ans})
    return render(request, 'keyword.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: but i want to give a default value as well .. can i achieve both the things

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the example I linked to, pass the `initial` to the form that is instantiated near the bottom. That's the one that is going to be sent to the browser before the user fills out anything.